# Make watch feature e-mail post contents for PHPBB

Tags: forums

I use PHPBB's watch post/forums feature quite a lot. I get really tired of having to click on the e-mail to go to the board and see the new posts though. Is there some way to make it so that the e-mail that tells me there is new contents can just also contain the new contents as well?

This is an install that I control, so I can even change the source files if need be...